# How to obtain "B2C JWT Access Token" from the signed in User?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I'm working with a .Net Core Web API and a .Net Core Web MVC Application. They both use Azure AD B2C to authenticate users. But in order to get a response from a HttpRequest from the Web API I need to provide the JWT Access Token from B2C for the signed in user on my web MVC application. Is there a way to obtain this access token inside a controller using the authenticated "User".

I have tried accessing the claims of the signed in user but no luck there, I have also used jwt.ms to review that the B2C workflow works well and that the JWT token is being generated and it works as well. The MVC application is authenticating the user and the web API is working fine with a hardcoded token. I just need to obtain the access token from a signed in user rather than doing it hardcoded.

I expect to be able to get the B2C JWT access token so that I can later on pass it to the Web Api and be able to secure my requests.

Comment: Another information that might help is that I'm using the B2C template for the .Net Core Web MVC Application that uses AzureADB2C.UI Nuget package to obtain the JWT from Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting some help from the MS AzureADB2C.UI GitHub crew we were able to solve the issue. The issue was that the tokens aren't saved by default on the library, so we needed to configure OIDC to specify that the tokens have to be saved for future use within the application. And so here is the example code of the "Startup" configuration and the example of how to query the "JWT access token" from the controller.

Startup.cs:

```
    services.Configure(AzureADB2CDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options => {
            options.SaveTokens = true;
    });
```

Controller:

```
    string idToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
```

More information on how was the issue solved can be found on the following link:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/11424

Comment: Hi @Andre Does this save the access token as well?

Comment: Yes @ChrisPadgett it does.

Comment: Thank you, Andre, I believe the AzureADB2C.UI package *doesn't* refresh the access token after it has expired. I've created a sample application that do this using MSAL.NET. I've updated my other answer with a reference to the sample application that can be found [here](https://github.com/chrispadgettlivecom/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNetCore22).

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [this sample application](https://github.com/chrispadgettlivecom/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNetCore22).

It uses [the ASP.NET Core Azure AD B2C middleware](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI) to authenticate the end user and [MSAL.NET](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) to acquire, cache, and refresh the access token.

The access token is acquired in [the **AzureADB2COpenIdConnectOptionsConfigurator** class](https://github.com/chrispadgettlivecom/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNetCore22/blob/9129764380f271346a7c7eb786a4142293d208eb/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNetCore22/AzureADB2COpenIdConnectOptionsConfigurator.cs#L40).

A code example for a controller method referencing the access token is [here](https://github.com/chrispadgettlivecom/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNetCore22/blob/9129764380f271346a7c7eb786a4142293d208eb/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNetCore22/Controllers/HelloController.cs#L25).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Chris, but B2C is already providing me (my site with the nuget package above) with an initial JWT. Is there no way to access this initial token anywhere? Must I manually fetch additional tokens?

Comment: Hi @AndreVigneault I've updated the above answer with reference to the AzureADB2C.UI package.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the actual token string you need? If so, you can access the headers using the HttpContext within the controller? The HttpContext will have a collection of headers that were passed in

Comment: It's actually the original JSON Web Token, from B2C string that I need, but I need to access it from the MVC controller from the Web App. I tried your suggestion but after looking at the HttpContext headers I still don't see the token string. Would you happen to have any code example or snippet that I may be able to look at?

Comment: @AndreVigneault as far as I know, it should should up as the header with key `Authorization` and value `Bearer <token here>`. Do you not see an Auth header at all?

Comment: What i’ve said “should” be correct.. Have you added the IHttpContextAccessor to the ServicesCollection registration and injected it into your controller to access the headers? I’ll dig out some example code for you

Comment: Thank you for the follow up Robert, yes I'm using IHttpContextAccessor, but still can't find the JWT token, the code example would surely be useful if you have any.